# Where is my "Configure User Tools" button in Visual Studio Source Control options?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, version-control, beyondcompare

I'm trying so set up Beyond Compare as my Visual Studio 2015 compare tool, and ever once of the first 10 Google hits tells me to click the Options->Source Control->Configure User Tools button.

There is no such button under my my Source Control options, and in fact there is only one option there, and it is the "Source control plugin" dropdown.

I did find one set of instructions, on the Beyond Compare site itself, that only requires I select the correct Source control plugin, but it requires editing the .git repo config file for each new project. That is not an acceptable solution.

What is wrong with my Visual Studio?

Comment: Please can someone explain the down-vote. SO unfortunately lacks mandatory reasons for them, and the voter too lazy or cowardly to leave a comment stating their reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Git as your source control provider in Visual Studio, the instructions are:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Select Options from the Tools menu.
3. Select Plug-In Settings under the Source Control branch of the
   left-side tree control.
4. Select Microsoft Git Provider under Plug-In Settings on the
   right-hand pane.
5. After starting a project in a Git repository, edit the config file
   in the .git folder in the project folder.
6. Change the config file to reflect the following changes:

   ```
   [diff]
       tool = bc4
   [difftool "bc4"]
       cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
   [merge]
       tool = bc4
   [mergetool "bc4"]
       cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 4\\BComp.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
   ```

Source: http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#visualstudio-git

The instructions you referenced with the "Configure User Tools" button is for projects that use Team Foundation Server, they aren't valid for Git.

Comment: This is a bit of a cumbersome solution. I don't blame you, but editing the git config on creating each new project will require some scripting to automate it, or it's just really a hassle.