# How do I use a custom diff tool for specific file types in Visual Studio (with Git)?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, diff

I want to use a custom diff-tool in Visual Studio (2019) for specific file types, for example, I want to use the default visual studio diff tool for every other file type *except* for `.xls` and `.xlsx` extensions.

My use case is similar to [Setup 'git diff' for special file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069976/setup-git-diff-for-special-file-types), however, I want to do it in Visual Studio (with git-scm).

#### `~/.gitconfig`

```
[diff "excel"]
    command = <path_to_my_diff_tool_for_xls>
```

#### `~/.gitattributes`

```
*.xls   diff=excel
*.xlsx  diff=excel
```

I have tried doing this at a repository-level and at a global-level with no success - Visual Studio just doesn't seem to pickup my diff-tool when I try to compare `.xls` files. It works successfully when I run `git diff` in the command-line - just not through the VS GUI.

Is there a reason that Visual Studio doesn't respect my diff-instructions in `.gitattributes`?

---

I found that when adding a local `.gitattributes` file through Visual Studio (Team Explorer > Settings > Repository Settings) it will generate a default, commented attribute file.

Within this file:

```
###############################################################################
# Set default behavior for command prompt diff.
#
# This is need for earlier builds of msysgit that does not have it on by
# default for csharp files.
# Note: This is only used by command line
###############################################################################
#*.cs     diff=csharp
```

This wording (to me, atleast) implies that VS might not respect these types of entries in the `.gitattribute` files (besides through command prompt).

---

*note*: I am aware that I can [override the diff tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902529/where-is-my-configure-user-tools-button-in-visual-studio-source-control-option), but I **only** want to use this tool on excel files and I can't find a way to do that like [you could in TFS with the Configure User Tools popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare).